# Pass additional parameters to method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, delegates, devexpress

I am using `Devexpress` file upload control. I am making using of the following `overload` in the `UploadControlExtension` class:

```
public static UploadedFile[] GetUploadedFiles(string name, UploadControlValidationSettings validationSettings, EventHandler<FileUploadCompleteEventArgs> fileUploadCompleteDelegate);
```

My complete event method signature looks like:

```
public static void AttachmentUploadedCompleteEvent(object sender, FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
```

What I am trying to do is pass in additional parameter to my `AttachmentUploadedCompleteEvent()` method. So I want the signature to change to

```
public static void AttachmentUploadedCompleteEvent(object sender, FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e, bool isAdmin)
```

But of course if I change to the above then I get an error:

> cannot convert from 'method group' to 'out string[]'

My knowledge on `Delegates` is not the best so I was hoping someone could point me to the right direction on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required to provide a method that is compatible with the [signature of the delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). Which means, the 3rd parameter to `GetUploadedFiles` must be a method which takes an `object` and a `FileUploadCompleteEventArgs` as parameters, and returns void.

You could pass a lambda to "curry" your function:

```
GetUploadedFiles(name, validationSettings, (s, e)=> { AttachmentUploadedCompleteEvent(s, e, isAdmin); }
```

The lambda expression is an *anonymous method* that MATCHES the signature of the required delegate, and yet you can pass another parameter to your original method.

Comment: Thanks for this! it was exactly what I required. You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Glad you say this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change Delegate declaration like

public delegate void AttachmentUploadedCompleteEventHandler(object sender, FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e, bool isAdmin)